# Cannot pick the first element of combobox in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this combo-box in jQuery-mobile, but I can't seem to pick the first element. How do I pick the first element?

(if i'll pick some other element and there i'll pick the first - it will be fine)

html

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" >
<label for="select-choice-1" class="select" style="text-align:right">Pick num</label>
<select name="select-choice-1" id="KOKO">
</select>
</div>
```

javascript

```
myArray1 = new Array(
           );

           var i, z;

           for (i = 28,z=0; i < 39; i++,z++)
           {
               myArray1[z] = i;
           }

           $("#KOKO").html('');
           for (var i = 0; i < myArray1.length; i++) {
               row = myArray1[i];
               $("#KOKO").append(
                   '<label for=' + row + '>' + row + '</label>' +
                   '<option value='+row+'>' + row + '</option>');
           }
           $('#KOKO').trigger('create');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/goldsoft/x6xd4zkp/1/

Comment: Do you mean that because there is only one item to select, it doesn't allow you to select the first item. If there is only one item, the onChange event won't fire? If so, just add another option first with the text "Pick Number" and drop the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting `28` as your default value? In any case, you don't need it to be 28, it can be a text placeholder, then 28 will be your second, and selectable value.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6xd4zkp/5/)

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select" style="text-align:right">Pick num</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="KOKO">
        <label for="28">28</label>
        <option value="28">28</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

For setting it back to a value of your choice, see...

[jQuery Mobile Docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)

and scroll to the section **Refreshing a select**

Comment: thanks for the help :)   how to set this combobox to the first element by pressing button after i select Different element ?

Comment: That wasn't part of your original question, but I updated the fiddle link in my answer to show you. If this helped you, please mark this as the answer. Thanks